# Rectangle not being drawn on screen (Java GUI)

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, bufferstrategy

I'm currently watching RealTutsGML's tutorial on Java game development. In his tutorial, a black rectangle is drawn on the screen; however, after completing all the steps he has completed, a black rectangle is not drawn on my screen.

I've researched this problem for the past few days, but I have not found any solution.

Thank you in advance!

```
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2368659607588750303L;
    private static final int WIDTH = 640, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;


    public Game() {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LETS BUILD A GAME", this);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        running = true;
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join(); //stops thread
            running = false;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        //game loop
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;

        while(running == true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) /ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }

            if(running == true) 
                render();

            frames++;


            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }

        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {

    }
    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {    
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). We don't know what a `Window` is, for starters.. Another tip is not to give the same name for a custom class as one in the API. Perhaps this one might better be called a `GameWindow`.

Comment: You are using some AWT or swing based library. Doing the above immediately in swing would be more obvious code. Search keys: `JFrame, swing timer, JPanel, paintComponent`.

Comment: BTW - even if the `render()` method is called, nothing will change each time it runs. Also, there is no call to render a rectangle at any point in the code. *"watching RealTutsGML's tutorial on Java game development"* Consult a better tutorial, or read that one more carefully. (shrugs - you didn't link to it.)